# Ubuntu 13.04 Unity black and white pixilated screen after suspend resume

Tags: unity, 13.04, suspend, gui, macbook-pro

Whenever I suspend and resume my laptop I get the following screen (see link to image below). I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to TTY and I can kill and restart Unity but it seems to have no effect when I try to go back using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. Interestingly this only happens when I don't have my secondary monitor plugged in. When the secondary monitor is plugged in the system resumes to the GUI fine.

I looked at `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` and didn't see any errors or anything that jumped out as suspicious. Has anyone else experience this or know where I can look to diagnose the issue?

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -i MacBook 

    Product Name: MacBookPro8,2
    Family: MacBook Pro
    Version: MacBookPro8,2
```

When the computer resumes music that had been playing when I suspended the computer  will resume playing. So I believe it is resuming correctly it's just the graphics that are getting messed up for some reason.

EDIT: A workaround that seems to work is to plug in my external monitor and then login. However carrying around my external monitor and a power source would be extremely inconvenient :) but hopefully this gives a clue to what's actually going on.

Also doing this causes my main display's desktop to be black. While I can drag windows onto my main monitor and my toolbar works (using cinnamon) the background image does not appear (it flickers on then off when i try to change the background). I also cannot right click on my main monitor background but I can on my secondary (laptop) background.

Killing and restarting cinnamon does not fix the background issue either.

[image]

Comment: could you run sudo dmidecode |grep -i MacBook  so we know what version of mac you have? Also are you running it in efi mode?

Comment: MacBookPro 8,2 and yes it is running in efi mode.

Comment: I always have trouble with suspend/resume with current kernel version (3.8). I tried to upgared to 3.9 and many issues are fixed but then My laptob abitrarily hangs so I'm back to 3,8. May be its Kernel issue?

Comment: No dice on updating the kernel to 3.9

Comment: what GFX card are you using in X? xvinfo |grep Adaptor , will tell you which one is in use by X. Also do you disable the other card?

Comment: Adaptor #0: "AMD Radeon AVIVO Video". To my knowledge I don't have anything disabled.